# Tips and tricks for test-first development

Tags: unit-testing, test-first

Just read this blog post - [Help! I’m Terrible At Migrating/Restructuring Code In A Test-First Manner](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/derickbailey/archive/2010/04/14/help-i-m-terrible-at-migrating-restructuring-code-in-a-test-first-manner.aspx).  I've had similar experiences, and thought I'd try an open it up to the wider community ...

Comment: While the charitable attitude is nice, this isn't really a question.

Comment: You say community there. This calls for CV. You should mark you post community wiki.

Comment: There are no tricks...No free lunch. You'll have to pay your technical debt - one cent at a time as you go along. Get your tips in the WELC book by Michael feathers, bite your lip and soldier on. Get back if you have some specific questions.

Comment: @Gishu - Thought as much - I have the Feathers book already and half way though it.  thanks for your comment - would have accepted as answer so +1

Answer (score 0):

I am using TFD – Test First development in a data migration project. I realize until you understand well the philosophy of TFD and the testing tool the development tend to be slow. But when you need to change your develop code you see the big benefits of TFD.  I think in TFD are tow rules that you always must not to break:

- Treat your testing code as first citizen. Clean code and always refactoring your testing code
- Never write code until you have a breaking test and implement the simplest code to pass your test.

If you always respect hose rules then is all about practice TFD.

For me I think I never again code without having a fail test.